# Running a Qt GUI application in Docker on Windows

Tags: windows, docker, qt

I have a Docker container based on an Ubuntu 20.04 image. In this Docker container, I want to open a Qt GUI. As host, I am using Windows 10.

When having a Linux machine as host, this setup is well discussed. For a Windows host however, this is not the case.

After finding [this website](https://dev.to/darksmile92/run-gui-app-in-linux-docker-container-on-windows-host-4kde), I tried to start the container with the following command:

`docker run --rm -it -e DISPLAY=host.docker.internal:0.0 mydockerimage:latest`

However, trying to run a Qt GUI results in the well known error

```
qt.qpa.xcb: could not connect to display host.docker.internal:0.0
qt.qpa.plugin: Could not load the Qt platform plugin "xcb" in "" even though it was found.
This application failed to start because no Qt platform plugin could be initialized. Reinstalling the application may fix this problem.

Available platform plugins are: eglfs, linuxfb, minimal, minimalegl, offscreen, vnc, xcb.

Aborted
```

After some research I noticed that the environment variable `QT_X11_NO_MITSHM=1` is required. So i changed the run command:

`docker run --rm -it -e DISPLAY=host.docker.internal:0.0 -e QT_X11_NO_MITSHM=1 mydockerimage:latest`

Strangely, all Qt GUIs worked just fine ... for some time. Out of nowhere, the above error started occuring again. I don't know what changed, but until know, I didn't manage to get it working again.

So it seems, that it is possible to run a Qt GUI in a Ubuntu Docker on Windows. But I seem to miss something as I can't manage to make it reliably work.

Does someone has a clue what's happening, an how to get the GUI applications run again?